# aviary (adobe creative SDK) in angular 2/4 can't access class variables when image editor is launched and save button is pressed

Tags: javascript, angular, adobe

I have created sample code on plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/kBZGz6pRlErV6hV08ctX?p=preview

everything works fine, but when editor is launched, i can't access class variables or any other member in class

```
imageCropMsg: string = "";
```

when editor launched, this variable and all other become undefined inside

```
onSave: function(imageID: string, newURL: string) {
    debugger;

    var img:any = document.getElementById(imageID);
    img.src = newURL;
    this.imageCropMsg = "Image Cropped Successfully";
    this.featherEditor.close();
}
```

unfortunately i couldn't find any reason and solved this issue.

Also, I'll highly appreciate if someone can improve code.

Answer (score 0):

This question related to the "this" context in javascript. Try changing function to arrow function.

```
onSave: (imageID: string, newURL: string) => {
            var img:any = document.getElementById(imageID);
            img.src = newURL;
            this.imageCropMsg = "Image Cropped Successfully";
            this.featherEditor.close();
        }
```

With this you have access to this and all the variables

Comment: Thank you for this help, with fat arrow function I have access to this.featherEditor in my case, but still can't access main class's other variables which are beyond this.featherEditor variable. Still my issue is not solved